# Finding the basis of a column space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, solution-verification

I was given the following question:

> Assume that $A$ is row equivalent to $B$. Find bases for Null A and Col A.  $$A=\left[\begin{matrix}-2&6&-2&-6\\2&-9&-6&2\\-3&12&5&-5\\\end{matrix}\right],B=\left[\begin{matrix}1&0&9&7\\0&3&8&4\\0&0&0&0\\\end{matrix}\right]$$

I know that to find the basis of the null space, I can set $A$ equal to zero and use the variables from the free columns. I also know that to find the basis of the column space I can just use all the rows with leading ones. My question involves the column space. In order to minimize this down into REF, do I put A and B into an augmented matrix? Or can I find the column space without using my B at all - by setting to zero in the same way as I do for my null space?

Edit:

Right now, I created an augmented matrix, and found the REF. My columnspace became: $$\left(\begin{matrix}1\\0\\0\\\end{matrix}\right),\left(\begin{matrix}-4\\1\\0\\\end{matrix}\right),\left(\begin{matrix}0\\\frac{-1}{2}\\1\\\end{matrix}\right)$$Is this correct?

Comment: Based on the premise, $B$ should be (almost) in row echelon form. In particular, A has rank 2, so the columnspace has to be 2 dimensional.

Comment: 1st and 2nd column of A form bases for column space of $A$.

Comment: @lc2r43 Can you explain what rank 2 means?

Comment: @Koro Can you explain why? How would I figure that out?

Comment: Clearly from B, rank of A=2. That is, dimension of column space of A =2. Column 1 and 2 are linearly independent in $A$. Hence, they are bases for column space of A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing row operations on $A$ doesn't change which columns are linearly independent.

In $B$, you can see that the first two columns are independent, and all others are linear combinations of those; more generally, in a RREF, if you look for the first nonzero entry in each row and circle those (in this case, that's entry $(1,1)$ and $(2,2)$) then the COLUMNS containing circled elements span the column space.

What about the null space? For each column NOT containing a circled entry (in this case columns 3 and 4), you can make the corresponding entries all zeroes except for a single $1$, so you create vectors
$$
\pmatrix{\star\\ \star \\ 0 \\ 1}, \pmatrix{\star\\ \star \\ 1 \\ 0}
$$
in your example; then you ask "what values must I put in to replace the stars to make these vectors satisfy $Ax = 0$? It'll turn out to be easy to answer that (from the row-echelon form), and that'll give you a basis for the nullspace.

Comment: So another column space is (1,0,0) and (0,3,0)

Comment: @Burt: No. The first sentence of this answer means that if column no. $a$ and column no. $b$ are linearly independent in $A$, then they are linearly independent in any matrix $X$, which is row equivalent to $A$. It really doesn't mean that column space of $A=$ column space of $X$.

Comment: @Koro I see. I thought that if matrix A and matrix B are row equivalent, they would have the same column basis - but that is not true. Thanks for clarifying.